# Junit Mocked bean is not executing

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5, spring-test

I'm using spring boot rest API and want to test my service layer. In my service I have autowired few beans and its not through constructor. (I like it that way to keep it short).

In the junit, I have created mocks and for private field which I do want to execute, I have assigned using *ReflectionTestUtils.setField*. When I debug, the method inside the field is not getting executed which assigned by bean.

**Service Class**

```
@Component
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    private MyRepository myRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ResponseMapper responseMapper;
    
    public List<MyObj> getList(String param) throws MyException {
        log.info("Getting details");
        Optional<List<MyObj>> list = myRepository.findByParam(param);
        List<MyObj> data = responseMapper.mapToResponseData(list);
        return data;
    }
}
```

**Test Class**

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private MyService myService;

    @Mock
    private MyRepository myRepository;
    
    @Mock
    private ResponseMapper responseMapper;
    
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(myService, "responseMapper", responseMapper);
    }
    
    @Test
    public void getListTest() throws Exception {
        when(myRepository.findByParam(anyString()))
                .thenReturn(Optional.of(getSampleList()));
        List<MyObj> list = myService.getList("param");
        assertTrue(list.size() >0);
    }
}
```

This results in Assertion failure and when I debug, the method *mapToResponseData* in ResponseMapper is not getting executed.

I know I can mock mapToResponseData method also. But I wanted it to execute so I don't have to write another test class for mapper alone.

What am I doing wrong? Is this the right wat to inject bean? And is using constructor in service to inject beans only option?

Comment: you have mocked the target method for repository : myRepository.findByParam(param), but not for the method call responseMapper.mapToResponseData(list). Can you mock responseMapper.mapToResponseData(list) method and try once.

Comment: @ManjunathHM With method mocking it works. But is there any way to execute that method without mocking. I dont want to create separate test class for the mapper class

Comment: while writing unit tests, you should mock the target methods of other dependency objects. If you write the Integration test cases then you can cover the entire flow in a single shot.